# Overbrace/underbrace without extending brackets/parentheses in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

**Avoid extending parentheses in equation in Microsoft Word**

I'm using \overbrace to explain a part of an equation, like this:

```
 cos⁡(⏞(log⁡(3) )^(θ=log⁡(3) ) )+2
```

But the overbrace increases the height of the brackets unnecessarily:

[image]

How do I avoid growing the parentheses, to get something like this instead:

[image]

Inspired by this question on tex.stackexchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213720/36898

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
Use the \smash function to ignore the extra height:

```
cos⁡(\smash(⏞(log⁡(3) )^(θ=log⁡(3) ) ))+2
```

Initially it looks like this:

[image]

But if you right-click on the equation, and click "Paragraph" you can adjust the "before"-spacing. Here it is set to 24 points:

[image]